# I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax of scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I feel stupid asking this, but I'm having a really hard time understanding the synatx of scipy.optimize

I have an mxm matrix M, and I simply like to find an m-dimensional vector x which

```
    minimizes M.dot(x)

    such that ||x||_2^2 = 1
```

Essentially I want to minimize Mx with x being l2-normalized.

I can't seem to find a way to fit my idea of what is going on within the syntax of numpy. I'd greatly appreciate any help in remedying my stupid with understanding.

---

The problem also has a special case where it can be solved by finding x such that

```
    M.dot(x) = zeros

    such that ||x||_2^2 = 1
```

Would the same optimization algorithm be appropriate for both problems? Or are there different ways to solve the minimization and finding zeros problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function to minimize is:

```py
def f(x, M):
    return M.dot(x)
```

Your starting point can be anything, say,

```py
m = M.shape[0]
x0 = np.ones(m)/np.sqrt(m)
```

You can apply the constraint as:

```py
def con(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x) - 1

cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun': con}
```

Finally, the minimization should run as:

```py
scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0, args=(M,), constraints=cons)
```

Lots of options can be changed, and very well might be necessary for your problem, but hopefully this helps you apply the syntax of the module to your problem.  See [these examples for more information](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

---

In the case where the right-hand-side is zero, your problem is linear and can be solved more directly, for example, with `scipy.linalg.solve`:

```py
from scipy import linalg

x = linalg.solve(M, np.zeros(M.shape[0]))
```

I don't know how to implement the constraint here, but I believe it can simply be added after the fact, since in this case it would hold with any constant multiplier:

```py
x /= linalg.norm(x)
```

Comment: I missed the constrain that the magnitude of the solution must be `1`. Unfortunately, that makes it non-linear.

Comment: @Joe Isn't it still linear in the case where the rhs is zero?

Comment: It depends on the number of observations. If it's an underdetermined problem, adding the a-priori constraint that `x` must have a norm of `1` can allow you to solve it.  I was guessing (?) that that's what the OP was trying to do. In retrospect, I may have been reading too much into it.  Either way, excellent answer on your part!

Comment: @Joe That makes sense, thanks.  I'll leave my answer as is and these comments can stand as a warning.